# How to get attribute of datalist option onclick - reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a reactjs project where i am using semantic ui to simulate an search-autofiill. I have created a search input where user can entre the search data and get the list of data from an get request (local server) . the list is getting populated dynamically and results are shown please refer the below image.

[image]

but the GET request i am making has an extra value called id which i have to retrieve it together with the value called key (testtask which you can see on the image). how can i achieve this? 
Below is my code :

```html
<div className="logoutautocomplete">
            <div>
                <Input list='languages' placeholder='Enter countrydata' onChange={this.onChangeSearchInput} />
                <datalist id='languages' value={this.state.data.country} >
                  {this.state.countryData.map((e, key) => {
      
                    return <option value={e.Key} data-id={e.Id}  >{e.Key}</option>;
                    {/* i am able display the key and get the value . i need the value of e.id to be returened to my onChangeSearchInput */} 
})}
                  </datalist>
                  
            </div>
 </div>
```

```html
onChangeSearchInput(e) {
    console.log("this value", e.target.value.data);

    GetData(e.target.value).then(result => {
      //this.state.data.splice(updateIndex, 1);
      
      this.setState({ countryData: result.searchCountry }); // i am setting the array hear
      console.log("result is", this.state.countryData);
    });


  }
```

```html
// Json data i am adding into countrydata
{
    "searchCountry": [
        {
            "Key": "Testtask",
            "Id": "2"
        },
        {
            "Key": "Testtask",
            "Id": "3"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: your question is very unclear - please explain more clearly what you are trying to do, what you have now and what missing - maybe edit your code examples and add the missing parts

Comment: I don’t think that’s possible using `datalist` - there is no event that would fire when the user makes their choice, that would allow you to access the selected option. The only events you will receive are related to the input field, but from that you can only read the value that was inserted, but not anything else, because that information is simply not there. If your option values were unique, you could loop over the datalist options to find the id corresponding to a value, but if the real situation is like your example, where there’s two “Testtask” options, that won’t work either.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue and I wanted `<datalist>` to work like `<select>`.
I couldn't find an acceptable solution, but this simple light-weight package saved my day!! [React HTML Datalist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-html-datalist)